# Differences Between " P1SEL |= BIT5 + BIT6 " vs " P1SEL= BIT5 | BIT6 " in embedded C

Tags: code

Is there any difference between " P1SEL |= BIT5 + BIT6  "  vs " P1SEL= BIT5 | BIT6 ". If there is , what is it?

Comment: The first one preserves any set bits, the second one does not.

Comment: So , if we would like to set BIT5 and BIT6 without pay attention to other pins , could we use both of them?

Comment: Forget about the addition, this is the same as x=y vs x = x | y. One is destructive to "x", the other one is not. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: The comments are trying to give you a hint that you almost certainly have a typo in the second example. Please read your question carefully and make sure the code examples are correct.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a (probably C, you don't even specify) programming question; that's not on scope for the electrical engineering stack exchange. You'll have to look up the definition of these operators for your programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The `|=` operator, like all compound operators, is the equivalent of the first operator (`|`) used on the left-hand side value and the right-hand side value, then an assignment (`=`) to the left-hand side.

So `a |= b` is the equivalent of `a = a | b`.

In your case, `P1SEL |= BIT5 + BIT6` is the equivalent of `P1SEL = P1SEL | (BIT5 + BIT6)`.

So it takes the current value of P1SEL, and does a logical OR with the `BIT5 + BIT6`. This means that bits that are 0 in `BIT5 + BIT6` (most likely, all bits but bits 5 and bit 6) are unchanged, while bits that are 1 in `BIT5 + BIT6` (most likely, bits 5 and 6) will be set to 1.

In other words, it sets bits 5 and 6 to 1, and leaves all the rest untouched.

On the other hand, `P1SEL= BIT5 | BIT6` just sets the value of P1SEL to `BIT5 | BIT6`. This means bits 5 and 6 are set, while all the others are set to 0.